# Skipping lines in a large file, then pipe to external command in Nushell

Tags: nushell

I'm trying to write a very simple Nushell script. I want to skip the first 46 lines and pipe the rest to an external command. In Bash:

```
zcat filename.sql.gz |
    tail -n +46 |
    mysql dbname
```

Since Nushell's `open` doesn't seem to support compressed formats, I extracted the `.gz` and then, in Nushell, tried:

```
> open --raw filename.sql | lines | skip 46 | describe
list<string>
```

...so I have a list, therefore I should be able to convert it to one string, but...

```
> open --raw filename.sql | lines | skip 46 | to text | mysql dbname
```

It appears as though that tries to load the whole file into memory, but it's much too large. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: (A) In `zcat filename.sql.gz` & in `open --raw filename.sql` we have file name mismatch. Is that intentional ? (B) Can you make `filename-46.sql` earlier (one time) to use that Directly on mysql ?

Comment: @Prem (A) I edited the question to clarify the name-mismatch, since it's explained in the OP's [Github issue](https://github.com/nushell/nushell/issues/6570) on the same topic. (B) would run into the same issue (would try to process the entire file in memory before writing to `filename-46.sql`) as long as `to text` is being used.

Comment: What I intended to say was :: "When OP converted sql.gz to sql, OP could very well have removed the 46 lines making sql-46 , then mysql can Directly use that new file sql-46 without getting into nushell Issues" :: Your Solution in nushell works too, but this is one alternative without nushell !

Comment: @Prem Ah, got it.  I get the feeling the OP was just trying to replicate the Bash version in Nushell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Important*:  As @Prem correctly mentions in the comments, my current answer below only works for a narrow  use-case, and can cause issues in most SQL-based workloads like in the question.  That it seems to have worked for the OP (based on current acceptance of the answer) is a happy coincidence.

See the bottom of this answer for the reasons why it is wrong, situations in which it might cause issues, and how we might (eventually) get it to work.

---

*Short answer* (addressing several of your issues), try:

```
zcat filename.sql.gz |
    lines |
    skip 46 |
    each {
        mysql dbname
    }
```

*Explanation:*

As fdncred mentioned in [your Github issue](https://github.com/nushell/nushell/issues/6570), the problem is the `to text`.

That's attempting to convert the *entire* `list<string>` to text.  That, of course, can't happen until the entire file is read.

What you really seem to want it to simply process each line as it is read.

You can see this demonstrated without feeding it to MySQL with something like:

```
open filename.mysql | 
    lines |
    skip 46 |
    each {
        bash -c "cat; echo"
        sleep 1sec
    }
```

<sub>^^^ Quick-and-dirty use of Bash to print what it receives on stdin (the `cat`) + a newline (the `echo`).</sub>

Note that there's some shorthand in there, primarily around implicit output, and the `each` block handling.  A more conventional, explicit-output, explicit-each-variable option:

```
open filename.mysql | 
    lines |
    skip 46 |
    each {|sql_statement|
        echo $sql_statement | bash -c "cat; echo"
        sleep 1sec
    }
```

Also, as you probably noticed in the "short answer", using this form you can return to using `zcat` to process the compressed file.

---

##### The "Oops" section

As mentioned in the front-matter, this doesn't work in all (perhaps most) cases.

The `each` will spawn a new `mysql` process for each *line* in the original file.  This often won't work, because SQL statements can span multiple lines.  Attempting to pass a single line of a multi-line statement into a single `mysql` process will fail.

I can think of a half-dozen different ways to make this work, but so far all of them would require changes to Nushell.

The *best* scenario, IMHO, would be for `to text` to stream as you original expected, which is a recent Nushell feature request ([#6178](https://github.com/nushell/nushell/issues/6178)).

Comment: Continuing my Comment to Question Post, I have a Query here : [ Is it going line-by-line to Single MYSQL Process ? (if yes, then ok) ] [ Or is Mysql getting executed once for each line ? (if yes, then that is a Problem) ] I am assuming there is Single MYSQL Process, otherwise it will not work !

Comment: @Prem I was wondering about that myself.  My assumption is that, if the original Bash version was working, then this Nushell equivalent should work as well.

Comment: The Original Bash version will always work , because there is a Single MYSQL Process , which is a "guarantee" by the PIPE Syntax. The nushell version may or may not have a Single MYSQL Process. Not knowing much about nushell , I think `each \{  COMMAND .... \}` will start `COMMAND` against each line. This will break , when the INPUT SQL Statement is longer than a Single line.

Comment: @Prem That is, of course, a great point.  You are correct that `each` is spawning a new MySQL process on each iteration, which is *not* the same as the Bash behavior.  Let me see if I can come up with an alternative that streams to a single process.